# How do I use update using hibernate where i am not sure on which field is to be altered?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

```
  public User updateUser(User user) {

    try {
        User result = session.get(User.class, user.getId());
        if (result == null) {
            throw new FilamentNoSuchRecordException(new CoreError(304, "User does not exist"));
        }
        session.clear();
        session.update(user);

        return user;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new FilamentDataConnectivityException(new CoreError(305,"Connectivity issue. Please see System Administrator"));
}
```

customer model is as follows

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "customers")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
 @DynamicUpdate(value=true)
 @SelectBeforeUpdate(value=true) 
 @SQLDelete(sql="Update customers SET deleted = true where customer_id=?")
 @Where(clause="deleted != true")
 @ApiModel(description="Create or update Customers")
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
 public class Customer {

 @Id
 @Column(name="customer_id")
 @NotNull
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int id = 0;

@Column(name="name")
@ApiModelProperty(value="The name of the customer", example="Mr J. Bond")
@NotNull
private String name;

@Column(name="description")
@ApiModelProperty(value="Desciption of the customer")
@NotNull
private String description;

@Column(name="logo_url")
@ApiModelProperty(value="Logo of user")
@NotNull
private String logo;

@Column(name="created_at")
@ApiModelProperty(value="The date the item was created", example="")
@NotNull
private Date createdAt;

@Column(name="updated_at")
@ApiModelProperty(value="The date the item was updated", example="")
@NotNull
private Date updatedAt;

@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<Application> applications = new HashSet<Application>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customers")
private Set<Service> services = new HashSet<Service>();

@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "customer_subscription",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id")
)
private Set<Subscription> subscriptions = new HashSet<Subscription>();

@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
private Set<Corpus> corpus = new HashSet<Corpus>();

@Column(name="deleted")
@NotNull
private boolean deleteFlag;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<Application> getApplications() {
    return applications;
}

public void setApplications(Set<Application> applications) {
    this.applications = applications;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

public Set<Service> getServices() {
    return services;
}

public void setServices(Set<Service> services) {
    this.services = services;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public Set<Corpus> getCorpus() {
    return corpus;
}

public void setCorpus(Set<Corpus> corpus) {
    this.corpus = corpus;
}

public Set<Subscription> getSubscriptions() {
    return subscriptions;
}

public void setSubscriptions(Set<Subscription> subscriptions) {
    this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
}

public boolean getDeleteFlag() {
    return deleteFlag;
}

public void setDeleteFlag(boolean deleteFlag) {
    this.deleteFlag = deleteFlag;
}
```

}

I check whether the object exists within the database, then update with an object, for example all fields could be null apart from the ID and the one thats needs to be updated. All fields are set to @NotNull in the model and I am using the @DynamicUpdate(value=true) and @SelectBeforeUpdate(value=true) annotations, but these seem to do nothing.

Just get failure saying the null fields can not be null. How do I update the row?

Comment: Why you are clearning the session? Also if fields can be null then why did you put @NotNull annotation?

Comment: else i get the error " A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.uk.filament.models.Customer#4]"

Comment: hmm.. will see it in a min but you didn't answer my other question. Why did you put @NotNull annotation when you know fields can be null in DB? Also, if possible, paste User object.

Comment: The reason for @notNull is purely following some help articles for this problem. was saying to use this and the two other annotations

Comment: @NotNull is used when you don't want hibernate to save null values in your DB columns, which means, most probably you would have not-null constraints at your DB side. I'm assuming that entity you are trying to fetch has all the not-null fields populated in your table. Can you please try below code and see how it goes?

Comment: yes all fields have values, all i want to do is take an object fom (via post request) with ID as something,  and 1 or more fields with  value, the rest with null) and update those given fields, leaving the rest intact . what code below ?

Comment: Show the code handling the post request. Show some example JSON being posted. As it stands your question is unclear. Is this a Spring MVC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in above comments, try this -

```
public User updateUser(User user) {

    try {
        User result = session.get(User.class, user.getId());
        if (result == null) {
            throw new FilamentNoSuchRecordException(new CoreError(304, "User does not exist"));
        }
        result.setName(user.getName()); // update some properties
        session.update(result); // you should update 'result', not 'user'

        return result;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new FilamentDataConnectivityException(new CoreError(305,"Connectivity issue. Please see System Administrator"));
    }

}
```

Comment: This works ok. But I dont know which field is to be updated. The input is a user object with the ID set and which over field set to a 'updated' value. the rest null. my problem is that hibernate is trying to set those values in the table to null, instead of ignoring them

Comment: If your 'result' had name and description set, and then you fetched it and then you update just name then it will update just name and leave description untouched in DB. You must know which fields of entity you want to update. If your UI doesn't allow user to update description then of course you wouldn't call setDescription.

Comment: It did but I found a method of changing any field, whether you knew which it did not matter. See answer below. Thanks for all the help though

Answer (score 0):

By using this method I found in another stack overflow post solved the issue. This checks each field and uses the 'not null' value. Then i can update from an object with only 1 field changed.

```
public static <T> T getNotNull(T a, T b) {
    return b != null && a != null && !a.equals(b) ? a : b;
}
```